# javascript - String.Match() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Using the following string:

http://www.google.com.ar/setprefs?prev=http://www.google.com.ar/&sig=0_Kxz_cp1G52p8pcrDBlMIQhwJAL0%3D&suggon=2 https://plus.google.com/?gpsrc=ogpy0&tab=wX http://www.google.com.ar/webhp?hl=es&tab=ww http://www.google.com.ar/imghp?hl=es&tab=wi http://video.google.com.ar/?hl=es&tab=wv http://news.google.com.ar/nwshp?hl=es&tab=wn http://translate.google.com.ar/?hl=es&tab=wT https://mail.google.com/mail/?tab=wm http://www.google.com.ar/intl/es/options/ http://books.google.com.ar/bkshp?hl=es&tab=wp http://scholar.google.com.ar/schhp?hl=es&tab=ws http://www.google.com.ar/blogsearch?hl=es&tab=wb https://www.google.com/calendar?tab=wc https://docs.google.com/?tab=wo https://sites.google.com/?tab=w3 http://groups.google.com.ar/grphp?hl=es&tab=wg http://www.google.com.ar/reader/?hl=es&tab=wy http://www.google.com.ar/intl/es/options/ https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=es&continue=http://www.google.com.ar/ http://www.google.com.ar/preferences?hl=es http://www.google.com.ar/preferences?hl=es-419 http://www.google.com.ar/advanced_search?hl=es-419 http://www.google.com.ar/language_tools?hl=es-419 http://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=es http://www.google.com.ar/webhp?hl=es-419 http://www.google.com.ar/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=186645&form=bb&hl=es-419 http://www.google.com.ar/intl/es-419/ads/ http://www.google.com.ar/services/ http://www.google.com.ar/intl/es-419/privacy.html https://plus.google.com/112209395112018703654 http://www.google.com.ar/intl/es-419/about.html http://www.google.com/ncr javascript:void(0)

And this regex:

**(http://)(www.){0,1}(google.com.ar)[\S]***

This code:

```
var result = links.match(new RegExp("(http://)(www.){0,1}(google.com.ar)[\S]*"));
for(var i = 0;i<result.length;i++)
{
    alert(result[i]);
}
```

Gives me this output:

1. http://www.google.com.ar
2. http://
3. www.
4. google.com.ar

I have already tried to test the regex in http://regexpal.com/ and www.regextester.com, and in both cases the highlighted matches are correct, so i guess the problem is with the code.
I'm really new with javascript so i can't see the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ...what are you expecting that isn't happening?

Comment: "... not working as expected" What exactly **did**  you expect?

Comment: I expected the correct matches, for example the regex should match at least: http://www.google.com.ar/intl/es-419/about.html
But it does not do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `g` flag on your regex.

```
var result = links.match(/http:\/\/(?:www\.)?google\.com\.ar([\S]*)/g);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. But i need the webpage to be a variable, is there any way to archive this with the regex "format" i posted?

Comment: Well, if you loop through the `result` array, you can then test the regex again but without the `g` flag. This will allow you to get the subpatterns.

Comment: This is what i mean : new RegExp("(http://)(www.){0,1}("+ URL +")[\S]*"). I need a simpler way to get the links from **any** website (not including sub domains: http://groups.google.com.ar).

Comment: Thanks, i splited your pattern in two: http:\\/\\/(?:www\\.)? ([\\S]*)
And then checked:
links.match(new RegExp(pattern1+URL+pattern2,'gi'));